# Display div that is first in HTML beneath a div under it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to push down a div that is first (in HTML) so it goes beneath the div below. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="cinner">

<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2"></div>

</div>
```

Now, I would like container 1 to show beneath container2, I have put position:relative on "cinner" and have tried a bit with position:absolute on container2, but it just stacks on top of eachother, container1 does not push down. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify how must look the desired output ? and how looks now ? .... Inlcude your css attempt

Comment: I have included css attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options

**Without Using Flex**

Use `transform: scaleY(-1);` in both parent and childs to make it in reverse ordered

```css
.cinner {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
.cinner div {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="cinner">

  <div class="container1">container1</div>
  <div class="container2">container2</div>

</div>
```

**Using Flex**

Use `display:flex; flex-direction:column-reverse` in `.cinner` to make it in reverse ordered rows

```css
.cinner {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column-reverse
}
```

```html
<div class="cinner">

  <div class="container1">container1</div>
  <div class="container2">container2</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer using flexbox.

```css
.cinner {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container1 {
  height: 20px; 
  background: green; 
  order: 2
}

.container2 {
  height: 20px; 
  background: red; 
  order: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="cinner">

<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2"></div>

</div>
```